# cast without * operator

Tags: c, compiler-construction

Could someone explain to me what's happening to "n" in this situation?

main.c

```
unsigned long temp0;
PLLSYS0_FWD_DIV_A_DECODE(n);
```

main.h

```
#define PLLSYS0_FWD_DIV_A_DECODE(n) ((((unsigned long)(n))>>8)& 0x0000000f)
```

I understand that n is being shifted 8 bits and then anded with 0x0000000f. So what does (unsigned long)(n) actually do?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    unsigned long test1 = 1;
    printf("test1 = %d \n", test1);
    printf("(unsigned long)test1 = %d \n", (unsigned long)(test1));

return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
test1 = 1 
(unsigned long)test1 = 1
```

Comment: It's a cast without *.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It widens it to be the size of an `unsigned long`. Imagine if you called this with a `char` and shifted it 8 bits to the right, the anding wouldn't work the same.

Also just [found this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C) (look under right-shift operator) for why it's unsigned. Apparently unsigned forces a logical shift in which the left-most bit is replaced with a zero for each position shifted. Whereas a signed value shifted performs an arithmetic shift where the left-most bit is replaced by the dropped rightmost bit.

Example:

```
11000011 ( unsigned, shifted to the right by 1 )
01100001

11000011 ( signed, shifted to the right by 1 )
11100001
```

Comment: Hey, I'm no master of this stuff. I thought a shift was alway as logical shift. TIL arithmetic shifts.

Comment: If you shift to the right, widening the type does not help much.

Answer (score 2):

In your code example, the cast doesn't make much sense because `test1` is already an `unsigned long`, but it makes sense when the macro is used on a different type like `unsigned char` etc.

Also you should use `%lu` in `printf`  to print `unsigned long`.

```
printf("(unsigned long)test1 = %lu\n", (unsigned long)(test1));
//                              ^^
```

Answer (score 1):

> Could someone explain to me what's happening to "n" in this situation?

You are casting `n` to `unsigned long`.

> So what does (unsigned long)(n) actually do?

It will promote `n` to `unsigned long`.

Answer (score 0):

Casting the input is all it's doing before the bit shift and the anding. Being careful about order if operations and precedence of operators. It's pretty ugly.

But looks like they're avoiding hitting the sign bit and by doing this instead of a function, there's no type checking on n.

It's just ugly.

Better form would be to have a clean clear function that has input type checking.

Answer (score 0):

That ensures that `n` has the proper size (in bits) and most importantly is treated as unsigned. As the shift operators perform sign extension, when a number is signed and negative, the extension will be done with 1 not zero. It means that a negative number shifted will always result in a negative number.

For example:

```
int main()
{
        long i = -1;
        long x, y;

        x = ((unsigned long)i) >> 8;
        y = i >> 8;

        printf("%ld %ld\n", x, y);
}
```

On my machine it outputs:

> 72057594037927935 -1

Because of the sign extension in `y`, the number continues to be -1: